# Embedded hardware from software developer point of view

Tags: embedded, software

for the first time I have been facing a task to develop software for a given embedded hardware (Xilinx Zynq 7000 - [datasheet](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview.pdf)) from scratch. The software which I am going to develop will control electric drive of an electromobile. I have been looking for how to proceed in this situation. What is necessary to know about the hardware platform from the software developer point of view before starting coding? What is the appropriate sequence for studying individual features of new hardware? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you need the software to do? Talk over a UART - look at which UART is used in the hardware design, clock configuration - look at what frequency crystal is fitted and configure PLLs accordingly, etc. You need to understand the requirements of the software and how that fits to the hardware

Comment: What kind of hardware is "embedded hardware" to you? I know a company that puts >16-Xeon-cores boards with 256 GB of RAM into the backs of cars – that's embedded, just as much as programming a 200B program for an ATtiny that has 128 bytes of RAM. There might be slight differences in the problems encountered.

Comment: Thanks for adding your hardware to the question! See my answer – would it be possible to tell us what "control the electric drive" entails? How "close" to the transistor switching motor currents are you?

Comment: @Marcus Muller The goal is to implement the field oriented control algorithm of three phase induction motor. So the Zynq will directly switch the IGBT transistors.

Comment: If you are asking this question you are first of not going to port linux to this platform, you need to build the platform (fpga peripherals for the arm) to match a reference design and use the bootloader and linux port from that.  If you dont want to run linux then see the comments above and answers below being a programmable part, the peripherals for the processor the address space of where everything is mapped for the processor, etc, varies based on the fpga design.  You should really work together with the fpga designers to make sane interfaces and a sane address map and divide hw and sw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Zynq 7000 is a complex chip, but presumably you're part of a team that includes one or more hardware designers who are doing the PCB and FPGA fabric parts of the design.

For your purposes, you need a document that I usually call the "Hardware-Software Interface Specification". This document provides all of the details that the software developer needs in order to communicate with the hardware — the layout of the address space, and a complete description of how all of the hardware registers are laid out and what they do.

This document is mostly prepared by the hardware engineers, but you will have some input into the process, too — you will describe to them the kinds of information the software will need from the hardware and the kinds of things that the software will need to be able to do to the hardware. All of this will derive, of course, from the system functional specification, which all of you have already worked out with the marketing team.

In the meantime, you need to be reading up on the Xilinx SoC software development and debugging tools — there is plenty of documentation on these topics on their website.

---

In parallel with all of that, you'll also be developing the "Software Functional Specification" — a document that defines which parts of the system functionality are implemented in software and goes into greater detail about each of the tasks that must be performed. This will include things like power system status, motor control and the user interface. Based on this, you will make decisions about what kind of operating system to use — high-level (e.g., Linux), RTOS, or maybe even "bare metal". You will negotiate with the hardware developers about any tasks that need FPGA fabric support (hardware acceleration) in order to meet their requirements.

Comment: thank you for your reaction. My question is motivated by the fact that there is a lot of pieces of hardware in the Zynq SoC which I am not familiar with in the time being (mainly Memory management unit, Snoop control unit, DDR memory controller, AXI bus ). I don´t know what to study now and what later.

Comment: @Steve really, evalboard + examples for that evalboard. It will take you from "how to even do anything" to "blinking an LED from the FPGA" to "interfacing between the programmable logic and the CPU". It's a lot to unpack

Comment: @Steve: Unless you intend to program at the "bare metal" level, most of the pieces you mention will be taken care of by whatever operating system (RTOS or Linux) that you end up selecting. You'll see this if you follow Marcus's advice about starting on an evaluation board and working through some of the provided examples.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to extend on [Dave's excellent answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/494426/64158) (really, upvote that answer.):

The Zynq 7000 even gives you an even more important role in this project: It's a Frankenstein's system-on-chip that includes both a medium-sized FPGA and a (slow-ish, by modern standards) ARM applications processor.

So, if your job is to "own" the Zynq, it's your job to both design software to run on the ARM (typically, you'd run Linux or a similar operating system on that CPU), and to design the FPGA image, so you're doing both, hardware and software design.

That is quite a bit to do, and I can only stress what Dave said:

> In the meantime, you need to be reading up on the Xilinx SoC software development and debugging tools

... and honestly, get one of the many evaluatioon boards for 7000-series Zynq (the zedboard is quite popular), and work through the examples. You'll be happy if you know how to blink an LED through your FPGA from your CPU, I promise. That's basically what engineers in companies do, too: Learn how to use the device in an environment designed by those who took part in the design of the device. Without that, you'll spend far too many engineering hours on learning to take baby steps with the device, and thus, it's financially often a no-brainer that you buy the eval board, even if it costs a couple of thousand euros.

---

Looking at your application specifically: Your application

> will control electric drive of an electromobile.

If that just entails "telling the motor controllers that right front should go faster", well, then you can probably do that in software, and all you need the FPGA for would be electrically interfacing with these controllers.

If, on the other hand, you're supposed to be collecting back-EMF and hall sensor data to control the switching of power MOSFETs or IGBTs directly, then, well, you've got a problem that implies *hard real-time constraints* in the sub-microseconds order; and then, you can do practically nothing in software on an ARM applications processor core architecture with known uncertain interrupt latency, complex external memory, and all in all no optimization for these kind of workloads. You'll have to do most, if not practically all, of your processing in the FPGA – and that means that you're not a software developer anymore; you just got promoted to digital hardware designer, and possibly signal processing guru!